# Facebook Graph-Api: Get name of pages

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-fql

Iam new to the Facebook graph api.
I want to get all the names of the pages with more then a milion likes

This is my fql:

```
fql?q=SELECT name FROM page WHERE fan_count > 1000000
```

But i don't think that this is the right way. Is there a way to get all the names of the pages that meet the fql criteria?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, the [`page` FQL table](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/page/) is indexed only on id, name and username, not on fan count, so you can't query like this

Comment: Is there any other way that you know?

Comment: No, you'd need to build this manually by retrieving and caching the fan counts for pages you know the IDs of already